# Typescript error - Type X cannot be used as an index type

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, types, expo

My code is giving a Typescript error and I can't solve it. I've tried everything I could find on the internet, something about changing String to string, but still nothing works.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getPokemonDetails(){
            try {
                const response = await api.get(`/pokemon/${pokemonId}`)
                const {id, name, stats, abilities, types} = response.data

                const currentType = types[0].type.name as TypeName;
                const color = colors.type[currentType]

                setPokemon({
                    id, name, stats, abilities, color, types
                })
            } catch (error) {
                
            }
        }

        getPokemonDetails()
    })
```

In the **currentType** in

```
const color = colors.type[currentType]
```

is where it is giving error.

> Type 'TypeName' cannot be used as an index type.

```
type TypeName = {
    name: |
    'bug' |
    'dark' |
    'dragon' |
    'electric' |
    'fairy' |
    'fighting' |
    'fire' |
    'flying' |
    'ghost' |
    'grass' |
    'ground' |
    'ice' |
    'normal' |
    'poison' |
    'psychic' |
    'rock' |
    'steel' |
    'water'
}
```

```
export default {
    colors: {
        type: {
            bug: '#8CB230',
            dark: '#58575F',
            dragon: '#0F6AC0',
            electric: '#EED535',
            fairy: '#ED6EC7',
            fighting: '#D04164',
            fire: '#FD7D24',
            flying: '#748FC9',
            ghost: '#556AAE',
            grass: '#62B957',
            ground: '#DD7748',
            ice: '#61CEC0',
            normal: '#9DA0AA',
            poison: '#A552CC',
            psychic: '#EA5D60',
            rock: '#BAAB82',
            steel: '#417D9A',
            water: '#4A90DA',

        },
```

These are the parts of the code that I use where the error occurs. Can anyone help me find the error?

---

### UPDATE

I followed Zokki user's instructions and managed to remove the TypeScript error, but the same error appeared elsewhere, in the page's CSS file.

```
type TypeProps = {
    type: TypeName
}

export const Header = styled.View<TypeProps>`
    ${({theme, type}) => css`
        background-color: ${theme.colors.backgroundType[type]};
        height: 340px;
        padding: 20px;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    `}  
`
```

In the **type** in

```
background-color: ${theme.colors.backgroundType[type]};
```

the same error message happens "Type 'TypeName' cannot be used as an index type."

if I change it to **type['name']** or **type.name** the error disappears, but the application stops working correctly, it can no longer access the type.

This is the component where I pass the type

```
<S.Header type={pokemon.types[0].type.name} >
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type 'TypeName' is a Object-Type
So you have to use something like TypeName['name'] for

types[0].type.name as TypeName; -> types[0].type.name as TypeName['name'];

or even better is to use it like

```ts
const currentType = types[0].type as TypeName;
const color = colors.type[currentType.name]
```

Comment: Zokki, thanks for helping me. I follow what you instructed me to do and it worked, but I'm having the same error somewhere else. Could you help me again? I added new information to the question.